# Website using Persistent, Blaze-html, and Scotty

Tags: haskell

I know that my `let configFilePath = Prelude.head args` is unsafe and was wondering how I could handle it better. My deployment almost always has a file at `~/config.cfg` so I suppose I could have used `mayHead` then later `maybe` to safely default the filepath to `~/config.cfg`.

This was all done a little rushed, so I'd like to know how I did, how you would do it, if it's idiomatic, what should be changed, and if there are pieces I could factor out. Most importantly, I'd like to know if there are any bugs or unsafe things I've used.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies      #-}
import           Control.Monad                 (forM_)
import           Control.Monad.Logger
import           Control.Monad.Trans           (liftIO)
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource  (ResourceT, runResourceT)
import           Data.Configurator
import           Data.Text.Lazy                as T hiding (map)
import           Data.Time                     (UTCTime, getCurrentTime)
import           Database.Persist
import           Database.Persist.TH
import           System.IO                     (getLine)
import Prelude hiding (div)
import           Text.Blaze.Html
import           Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Text (renderHtml)
import           Text.Blaze.Html5              hiding (map)
import qualified Text.Blaze.Html5.Attributes as A   hiding (title)
import qualified Web.Scotty                    as S
import           MyBot.DomainChecker        (checkDomainAvail,
                                                getAuthCookies)
import Database.Persist.MySQL
import System.Environment (getArgs)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
DomainItem
  domain String
  active Bool
  createdAt UTCTime
  lastChecked UTCTime Maybe
  UniqueName domain
  deriving Show

Settings
  username String
  password String
  ppUsername String
  ppPassword String
  checkerDelay Int default=10
|]

runDb du dp x = liftIO $ withMySQLConn info $ \conn -> do
  (flip runSqlPersistM) conn x
  where info = defaultConnectInfo { connectDatabase = "ExpiredDomainBuyer", connectUser = du, connectPassword = dp }

blaze = S.html . renderHtml

getDBDetails :: FilePath -> IO (String, String)
getDBDetails filepath = do cfg <- load [Required "config.cfg"]
                           du <- require cfg "dBUser"
                           dp <- require cfg "dBPass"
                           return (du, dp)

toPageLink :: String -> String
toPageLink d = "/domain/" ++ d

checkSettingsEmpty du dp redirect = do
  emptySettings <- runDb du dp $ selectFirst [SettingsUsername ==. ""] [] :: S.ActionM (Maybe (Entity Settings))
  case emptySettings of
    Just settings' -> do
      liftIO . putStrLn $ "found empty settings"
      liftIO . putStrLn $ settingsUsername . entityVal $ settings'
      -- if there are no settings entries with valid (non empty) username
      -- delete all rows in settings table
      runDb du dp $ deleteWhere ([] :: [Filter Settings])
      -- create initial settings row
      runDb du dp (insert $ Settings "" "" "" "" 10)
      S.redirect redirect
    Nothing -> do
      liftIO . putStrLn $ "settings with non empty username found, probably valid... redirect to main"
      -- don't make this "/" or you'll redirect ;)
      S.redirect "/domain/list"

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let configFilePath = Prelude.head args
  putStrLn $ "config file: " ++ configFilePath
  -- (du,dp) <- getDBDetails configFilePath
  (du,dp) <- getDBDetails configFilePath
  runDb du dp $ runMigration migrateAll
  settings <- runDb du dp $ selectFirst [SettingsUsername !=. ""] []
  let checkerDelay = maybe 10 (settingsCheckerDelay . entityVal) settings
  putStrLn $ "Connected to db with username " ++ du

  S.scotty 3000 $ do
    S.get "/" $ do
      checkSettingsEmpty du dp "/settings"
    S.get "/domain/list" $ do
      -- checkSettingsEmpty du dp "/settings"
      domains_ <- liftIO $ runDb du dp $ selectList [] []
      let domains = map (domainItemDomain . entityVal) domains_
      blaze $ do
        body $ do
          h1 "Watched domains"
          p $ a ! A.href "/settings" $ "settings"
          addDomainForm
          deleteDomainForm
          ul $ do
            forM_ domains $ \domain -> do
              li $ a ! A.href (toValue . toPageLink $ domain ++ "/details") $ toHtml domain
    S.get "/domain/:domain/details" $ do
      domain_ <- S.param "domain"
      domain <- liftIO . (runDb du dp) . getBy $ UniqueName domain_
      case domain of
        Just domain' -> do
          let domainName = (domainItemDomain . entityVal $ domain')
          let timeCreatedStr = show . domainItemCreatedAt . entityVal $ domain'
          blaze $ do
            body $ do
              a ! A.href "/domain/list" $ "Back to domain list"
              h1 . toHtml . domainItemDomain . entityVal $ domain'
              if (domainItemActive  . entityVal $ domain') then do
                -- domain is active
                ul $ do
                  li $ pauseDomainBtn domainName
                  li $ deleteDomainBtn domainName
                else do
                -- domain is inactive
                ul $ do
                  li $ startDomainBtn domainName
                  li $ deleteDomainBtn domainName
        Nothing -> blaze $ h1 . toHtml $ domain_ ++ " not found"
    S.post "/domain/delete" $ do
      domain <- S.param "domain"
      _ <- liftIO . (runDb du dp)  . deleteBy $ UniqueName domain
      S.html $ T.pack $ "deleted " ++ domain
      S.redirect $ T.pack $ "/domain/list"
    S.get "/domain/add" $ do
      blaze $ do
        body $ do
          h1 "Add a domain"
          addDomainForm
    S.post "/domain/add" $ do
      now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
      domain <- S.param "domain"
      -- insert domain :domain :Active :created :lastChecked
      liftIO $ (runDb du dp) . insert $ DomainItem domain False now Nothing
      S.html $ T.pack $ "now watching " ++ domain
      S.redirect $ T.pack $ "/domain/" ++ domain ++ "/details"
    S.post "/domain/pause" $ do
      domain <- S.param "domain"
      liftIO $ runDb du dp $ updateWhere [DomainItemDomain ==. domain] [DomainItemActive =. False]
      S.html $ T.pack $ "paused " ++ domain
      S.redirect $ T.pack $ "/domain/" ++ domain ++ "/details"
    S.post "/domain/start" $ do
      domain <- S.param "domain"
      liftIO $ runDb du dp $ updateWhere [DomainItemDomain ==. domain] [DomainItemActive =. True]
      S.html $ T.pack $ "started " ++ domain
      S.redirect $ T.pack $ "/domain/" ++ domain ++ "/details"
    S.get "/settings" $ do
      settings <- runDb du dp $ selectFirst [SettingsUsername !=. ""] [] :: S.ActionM (Maybe (Entity Settings))
      case settings of
        Just settings' -> do
          let registrarEmail = settingsUsername . entityVal $ settings'
              registrarPass = settingsPassword . entityVal $ settings'
              paypalEmail = settingsPpUsername . entityVal $ settings'
              paypalPass = settingsPpPassword . entityVal $ settings'
          blaze $ do
            body $ do
              h1 "Expired Domain Bot Settings"
              updateSettingsForm registrarEmail registrarPass paypalEmail paypalPass checkerDelay
        Nothing -> do
          let registrarEmail = ""
              registrarPass = ""
              paypalEmail = ""
              paypalPass = ""

          blaze $ do
            body $ do
              h1 "Expired Domain Bot Settings"
              p " Initial setup, please enter your details"
              updateSettingsForm registrarEmail registrarPass paypalEmail paypalPass checkerDelay

    S.post "/settings/update" $ do
      u <- S.param "username"
      p <- S.param "password"
      pu <- S.param "paypalUsername"
      pp <- S.param "paypalPassword"
      checkerDelay <- S.param "checkerDelay"
      -- delete all entries since the valid settings are those we are getting
      runDb du dp $ deleteWhere ([] :: [Filter Settings])
      liftIO $ runDb du dp . insert $ Settings u p pu pp checkerDelay
      liftIO . print $ "redirecting to /domain/list"
      S.redirect "/domain/list"

addDomainForm = do form ! A.method "post" ! A.action "/domain/add" $ do
                     input ! A.name "domain"
                     input ! A.type_ "submit" ! A.value "Add Domain"

deleteDomainForm = do form ! A.method "post" ! A.action "/domain/delete" $ do
                        input ! A.name "domain"
                        input ! A.type_ "submit" ! A.value "Delete Domain"

-- updateSettingsForm :: String -> String -> String -> String -> Html
updateSettingsForm :: String -> String -> String -> String -> Int -> Html
updateSettingsForm user pass pe pp delay = do
  form ! A.method "post" ! A.action "/settings/update" $ do
    p $ do
      label "registrar email: "
      input ! A.name "username" ! A.value (toValue user)
    p $ do
      label "registrar password: "
      input ! A.name "password" ! A.type_ "password"  ! A.value (toValue pass)
    p $ do
      label "Paypal Username: "
      input ! A.name "paypalUsername" ! A.value (toValue pe)
    p $ do
      label "Paypal Password: "
      input ! A.name "paypalPassword" ! A.type_ "password" ! A.value (toValue pp)
    p $ do
      label "Checker Delay: "
      input ! A.name "checkerDelay" ! A.type_ "checkerDelay" ! A.value (toValue delay)
    p $ do
      input ! A.type_ "submit" ! A.value "Update Settings"


data DomainAction = Start | Pause | Delete
actionToStr Start = "start"
actionToStr Pause = "pause"
actionToStr Delete = "delete"
actionToStr _ = "invalid"

statusChangeBtn :: DomainAction -> String -> Html
statusChangeBtn a d = do form ! A.method "post" ! A.action (toValue $ "/domain/" ++ a') $ do
                           input ! A.name "domain" ! A.type_ "hidden" ! A.value (toValue d)
                           input ! A.type_ "submit" ! A.value (toValue $ a' ++ " Domain")
    where a' = actionToStr a :: String

pauseDomainBtn domain = statusChangeBtn Pause domain
startDomainBtn domain = statusChangeBtn Start domain
deleteDomainBtn domain = statusChangeBtn Delete domain
```

Comment: It has been almost four years. Do you want to review your own code by now?